# Privilege icons are missing from the help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

Privilege icons are not shown on the [help/privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) and [help/privilege/{privilegeName}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) pages.

There should be icons like this moderation privilege icon:

> [image: Moderation privilege icon]

When inspecting the code on the privilege page, the icon related code was there but the icon is not applied on the page:

> [image: Inspect an element]

The issue exists on all Stack Exchange sites.

**Configuration:**

OS: Windows 7
Mozilla Firefox : 59.0b5 (64-bit)
Google Chrome: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Previously the [privilege icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217338/312043) are available in this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch; these are now once again visible.